# Trouble with Python package Kivy on BeagleBone

Tags: python, kivy, beagleboneblack

I had some python 2.7 code that uses Kivy installed and running perfectly on a Raspberry Pi but it is crashing on the BeagleBone Black Rev C. The code imports:

```
from kivy import app
from kivy import clock
from kivy.uix import anchorlayout
from kivy.uix import label
from kivy.core import window
```

I'm running python 2.7 on BeagleBone Black Rev C with Debian Jessie. Kivy version 1.9.1. Here is the error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-01_6.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:48:22) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!

egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: No available video device
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "_window_sdl2.pyx", line 80, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1810)
  File "_window_sdl2.pyx", line 55, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1460)

x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

EDIT: Progress! I needed to install Cython. Once I did that, I got the following errors:

```
[ERROR ] [Window ] Unable to use pygame 
[ERROR ] [Window ] The module raised an important error: 'OpenGL not available'
```

Comment: Actually, the imports work like this `from kivy.app import App`, `from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout` i.e. classes, not whole files. Try them the correct way.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr: what would be more correct about that? It's generatelly recommended to do `import spam` instead of `from spam import eggs`: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function

Comment: @Wolph Well, I didn't see his code so nothing wrong with those imports generally, but he may screw something in the code because of the way he used them - call some function which shouldn't be called directly, "overwrite" a class and get errors.

Comment: This is all good information, but I think the problem has something to do with not being able to access OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install Kivy packages on Debian is by adding the Kivy repository.

Detailed instructions can be found here: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

Effectively it comes down to adding the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu trusty main
```

And run this command after:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A863D2D6
```

After that you can install Kivy:

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

Comment: Okay, so I am trying to uninstall Kivy, as I installed it using pip install Kivy. When I 
`python -c 'import kivy; print(kivy.__path__)'`
I get: `[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-01_11.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:48:22) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy']` but when I `sudo apt-get remove --purge python-kivy` I get a message `Package 'python-kivy' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: kivy also appears in pip list

Comment: I'm not certain where pip installs kivy on debian, perhaps that file is the one installed by pip. Regardless, it's safe to remove that directory and reinstall the package if you want to be sure that you have the correct version.